# AHK Text is getting cut off, can't find the issue

Tags: autohotkey

I can not see a reason why the text is getting cut off and could really use some outside help. The text %timers1% is getting cut off when it goes into double digits. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Gui, +LastFound +AlwaysOnTop +ToolWindow -Caption +Border +E0x08000000
Gui, Font, s20, Arial

timers := "00"

Gui, Add, Text, x3 y0 vTText1, %timers1%
Gui, Add, Text, x60 y0 vText1, Last

Gui, Add, Text, x3 y30 vTText, %timers%
Gui, Add, Text, x60 y30 vText, Current


Gui, Show, x0 y0 h60 w150, Stopwatch NoActivate
Settimer, Stopwatch, 1000
Return

Stopwatch:
timers += 1
if(timers < 10)
{
GuiControl, , TText ,  0%timers%
}
else
{
GuiControl, , TText ,  %timers%
}
return

GuiClose:
GuiEscape:
ExitApp
return

$~LButton::
Send f
return

$RButton::
Send {Tab 4}
Send {Enter}
Sleep, 50
Send ^{Tab}
timers1 = %timers%
GuiControl, , TText1 ,  %timers1%
timers := "00"
GuiControl, , TText ,  %timers%
return

!s::Suspend
```

Comment: It must be that the initial size of the text controls end up being too small as your text grows longer. Try giving it a large width beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

> ### GuiControl said:
>
> Since the control will not expand automatically, use `GuiControl, Move, MyText, W300` if the control needs to be widened.

So something like

```
if (strlen(timers) > 5)
    GuiControl, Move, TText, W200
```